# SumProduct and VLookup for selected columns

Tags: excel, sum, excel-2007, vlookup

I have a function that reads:

`=SUMPRODUCT(VLOOKUP(D17,'D:\Temporary Storage - not backed up and unsecured\[PT current plan.xls]Ore Fines'!$A$12:$BC$146,{4,8,12,16,20,24,28,32,36,40,44,48,52},FALSE)+VLOOKUP(D17,'D:\Temporary Storage - not backed up and unsecured\[PT current plan.xls]Lump Ores'!$A$12:$AY$146,{4,8,12,16,20,24,28,32,36,40,44,48},FALSE))`

The aim is to look for the matching date (Column D) in each relevant tab, then add up the cells corresponding to a column heading of "usage" only (the column heading repeat every 4 cells).

This returns the **#N/A** error; I am uncertain as to how to rectify this.

I have checked that the names, file paths, rows and columns are correct, and that any hidden rows, columns or tabs are clearly visible.

Any ideas?

### Edit 1

I have use the "Evaluate Formula" Tool which gives the following results. 
The first stage in the evaluation yields:

`SUMPRODUCT(VLOOKUP(41370,'D:\Temporary Storage - not backed up and unsecured\[PT current plan.xls]Ore Fines'!$A$12:$BC$146,{4,8,12,16,20,24,28,32,36,40,44,48,52},FALSE)+VLOOKUP(D17,'D:\Temporary Storage - not backed up and unsecured\[PT current plan.xls]Lump Ores'!$A$12:$AY$146,{4,8,12,16,20,24,28,32,36,40,44,48},FALSE))`

Stepping into this shows the corresponding date: 6 Apr 2013 (the date in cell D17)

The second stage:
`SUMPRODUCT(#REF!+VLOOKUP(D17,'D:\Temporary Storage - not backed up and unsecured\[PT current plan.xls]Lump Ores'!$A$12:$AY$146,{4,8,12,16,20,24,28,32,36,40,44,48},FALSE))`

the third stage:
`SUMPRODUCT(#REF!+VLOOKUP(41370,'D:\Temporary Storage - not backed up and unsecured\[PT current plan.xls]Lump Ores'!$A$12:$AY$146,{4,8,12,16,20,24,28,32,36,40,44,48},FALSE))`

The fourth stage:
`SUMPRODUCT(#REF!+#REF!)`

The fifth stage:
`SUMPRODUCT(#REF!)`

And finally:
`#N/A`

Comment: Try using the 'Formulas' > 'Evaluate Formula' feature to see what the results of the VLOOKUP are? It's hard to tell without knowing what the `VLOOKUP`s return.

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. I've edited the post appropriately.

Comment: `#REF!` is usually thrown when the reference cannot be found, so if you've checked the path, I'm not sure what's wrong. If that's fixed though, wrap `SUM()` around each VLOOKUP since you have arrays of different sizes.

Comment: @Jerry, That's done the trick! thank you!

Comment: Oh? I'll put that as an answer then. The path was correct then?

Comment: Indeed it was. As you said, it was the varying array lengths that caused the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap `SUM()` around the `VLOOKUP`s:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUM(VLOOKUP(D17,'D:\Temporary Storage - not backed up and unsecured\[PT current plan.xls]Ore Fines'!$A$12:$BC$146,4,8,12,16,20,24,28,32,36,40,44,48,52},FALSE))+SUM(VLOOKUP(D17,'D:\Temporary Storage - not backed up and unsecured\[PT current plan.xls]Lump Ores'!$A$12:$AY$146,{4,8,12,16,20,24,28,32,36,40,44,48},FALSE)))
```

When you have arrays of different sizes, when both are larger than one element long, you will get an error, for example:

```
=SUMPRODUCT({1,2}+{1,2,3})
```

Will give an error because the arrays are not of the same size. A quick fix is the `SUM()`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUM({1,2})+SUM({1,2,3}))
```

Which adds up each element in the arrays first.